# Elastic search for json array

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a json file and I want to load the json file into elastic search so I did,

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/datas/data/1' -d @rosia_data.json
```

but it produce som error as:

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[Malformed content, must start withno bject]","status":400}
```

My data is something like this:

```
[
{
"sr":"Krishna Chaudhary", 
"inventory":"Vector Plus - 2`S",
"packaing_unit":"pcs",
"shopname":"D&b Store",
"shoproute":"RCT Market",
"quantity":12,
"order_id":21745,
"distributor_name":"New Horizon Distributors Itahari",
"distributor_id":13,
"order_date":"2014-06-01"
  },
  {
 "sr":"Krishna Chaudhary",
  "inventory":"Vector Plus - 4`S",
  "packaing_unit":"pcs",
  "shopname":"D&b Store",
  "shoproute":"RCT Market",
  "quantity":12,
  "order_id":21746,
  "distributor_name":"New Horizon Distributors Itahari",
  "distributor_id":13,
  "order_date":"2014-06-01"
 },
 {
 "sr":"Khagendra Pokhrel",
"inventory":"Vector Plus - 4`S",
"packaing_unit":"pcs",
"shopname":"Samita Cosmetic",
"shoproute":"Pathri",
"quantity":12,
"order_id":21762,
"distributor_name":"Horizon Distributors Damak",
"distributor_id":14,
"order_date":"2014-06-01"
 }
]
```

so please help me to solve this problem.
BTW I am new to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Can you show @rosia_data.json content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,By this you only can index a document (But your json is array or documents, which gives error) . 
If you need to index multiple documents just use [bulk api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

For example look at the [link.](https://gist.github.com/rbnacharya/e8ff2eb38600ed978301)

Comment: how to load the data with bulk api. Can you give a example?

Comment: I am getting this error:
    {
    "error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1:      no requests added;]","status":500}

Comment: make sure, you only don't have linebreaks in a json , look at my gist. it will work

Comment: so my .json file is 3mb and do i have to manually include
    {"index" : {"_index" : "datas" , "_type" : "data" , "_id" : 1}}
in each inner array of json file.

Comment: You should just make structure as i've written (yes append the string, and don't use as array), or you should write a script(probably using python) .